# Cannot Import Modules from Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hey so I am having trouble importing modules from Tensorflow in my program. I installed it successfully without issues. However I am getting a "Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime." error message. The stack trace is below. Please let me know if you can help.
Thank you!

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
> line 58, in 
> from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
> line 28, in 
> _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
> line 24, in swig_import_helper
> _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/imp.py",
> line 242, in load_module
> return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/imp.py",
> line 342, in load_dynamic
> return _load(spec) ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so,
> 6): Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin   Referenced from:
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)   Expected in:
> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib  in
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "close_price_predict.py",
> line 1, in 
> from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Flatten, Dense, Dropout, Activation   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py",
> line 41, in 
> from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py",
> line 50, in 
> from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
> line 69, in 
> raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
> line 58, in 
> from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
> line 28, in 
> _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
> line 24, in swig_import_helper
> _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/imp.py",
> line 242, in load_module
> return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/imp.py",
> line 342, in load_dynamic
> return _load(spec) ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so,
> 6): Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin   Referenced from:
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)   Expected in:
> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib  in
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib

Comment: can you provide the version on Tensorflow your installed ? From Tensorflow docs : ```Python 3.8 support requires TensorFlow 2.2 or later.``` at : https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#:~:text=System%20requirements,-Python%203.5%E2%80%933.8&text=Python%203.8%20support%20requires%20TensorFlow%202.2%20or%20later.

Comment: Its tensorflow version 2.4.0

Comment: I suspect your cpu model does not support AVX instructions sets. You can check [hardware requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python3#hardware-requirements). Make sure to download the latest [microsoft visual c++ redistributable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0) and follow the instructions to install from [Tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows).